# Exportar volcado de datos de Oracle a MySQL/PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql

Busco la manera correcta de exportar una base de datos *Oracle g10* de *16 gigas* a *MySQL* y/o *PostgreSQL*.

Digo exportar porque quiero tener el nuevo volcado de datos en formato para *MySQL*/*PostgreSQL* y luego hacer la migración.

Mantener los índices, codificación, procedures etc.

Creo que el gran problema siempre es la codificación de una base a otra.

Para esto, en producción tenemos *Windows Server* + *Oracle g10* + *Toad*.

Comment: Una opción podría ser el uso de herramientas diseñadas para ese fin: https://ora2pg.darold.net/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Hola quiero compartir mi solución actual, aun quiero automatizarlo.

Primero he intentado con `DBConvert` como me han sugerido y al parecer va bien hasta que se encuentra con estructuras, funciones o `defaults` que son completamente incompatibles de **oracle** hacia **mysql**

Entonces ahora estoy haciendo algo mas manual pero efectivo desde el `toad`:

selecciono la base de datos
selecciona la tabla y me da la solapa "`scripts`"
ahí mismo me da la estructura de oracle y con unas pequeñas adaptaciones la convierto a mysql. lo mismo con los indices y foreing keys, etc.

Luego tengo la opción de exportar los datos, aca el mismo problema que dbConvert, hay datos que son inexportables de oracle a mysql y el script generado es muy malo.

De varias opciones elijo

```
Export format => "sql statements"
destildo todas la casillas , excepto "allow empty files" y "automatic detect shema and name"
option "date format" => "YYYY-mm-dd"
option "time format" => "hh:mm:ss"
```

esto nos va a generar un .sql con los inserts necesarios.
Pero acá otra vez el problema con las fecha, te las genera en un formato raro y dentro de una función:

```
TO_DATE("2017-03-30 00:00:00","2017-03-30 00:00:00 Y COSAS RARAS")
```

Al importar el sql en mysql esto da error, prmiero por que la funcion TO_DATE que es de oracle no existe y segundo por que solo necesito importar la fecha.

Para resolver simplemente cree una función TO-DATE que recibe esos 2 parámetros y devuelve solo el primero que tiene el `datetime` y ya.

Al principio bastaba con reemplazar el texto que no necesitaba pero al trabajar con tablas tan grandes, .sql eran inabribles.

La función:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION TO-DATE(param1 varchar(30),param2 varchar(30)) RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
BEGIN
  RETURN param1 ;
END
//
```